# How do you tell if a HTML5 video is a live stream or just a video from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, html5-video

Creating a JavaScript Chrome Extension for YouTube, in which I would like to tell if the video is a live stream or just a stream.

Looking at the [HTML5 documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement), I've tried ondurationchange, with no success. Also tried to see if the "Live" element is in the YouTube HTML but it appears to always be there regardless:

```
var live = document.getElementsByClassName('ytp-live-badge');
```

Comment: There is no difference between a live stream and a stream. You'll simply have to look for indications within the HTML structure.

Comment: Can you get the length of the video? Maybe you could get the initial video length and then set up a timed event to check the length again a few seconds later, and see if it changed?

Answer (score 1):

For checking if the video on YouTube is a live stream, you're half-way there with querying for the `.ytp-live-badge` element. You just need to check whether it's disabled or not:

```
var liveBadge = document.querySelector('.ytp-live-badge');
var live = liveBadge && !liveBadge.getAttribute('disabled');
console.log(live);
```

Comment: That works, thanks! Just wondering, is a there an universal way to do this in the HTML5 API?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there's any plain-HTML5 way to do this; the only difference, I believe, is *perhaps* the protocol used for fetching data, and that's shaky (I think you can have an HTTP-based live stream, for example, and then you'd have to make an assumption based on the file extension). And, in any case, I don't think you can determine that on YT, since the `<video>` src is a `blob:` URL without any protocol/URL information.